# Deep Linking Facebook iOS - App don't open

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink, deep-linking

I have a problem with the integration of the Facebook deep linking (from a article to my app). I followed the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks) step by step, there is nothing to do, it doesn't work..

So in my website, I add the metadata :

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="...">
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="appname://event?event_id=127">
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="app name">
```

In my app delegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {



BFURL *parsedUrl = [BFURL URLWithInboundURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
if ([parsedUrl appLinkData]) {
    // this is an applink url, handle it here
    NSURL *targetUrl = [parsedUrl targetURL];
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Received link:"
                                message:[targetUrl absoluteString]
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation
        ];}
```

Did you have any idea why my app wasn't open ?
I also configure my Facebook app settings.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<meta property="al:ios:url" content="appname://event?event_id=127">` 
to 
    `<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myApp://event?event_id=127">`

Your app will recognize the scheme set by your url which is the **myApp** in this case (You can change it your desired string but both should match). So this should be present in your app's plist to recognize the incoming call to open.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myApp</string>
            <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: It doesn't work ... When you say myApp, I have to change myApp by the name of my app ?

Comment: mo bro u dont have to change app name what i suggested is schema name through which your app will identify the call back urls from facebook..it should match

Comment: Cheers ! it was helpful, all i make the web meta url and app schema equal for a callback by FB