# Facebook sharing with deep linking (app links) in Swift

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, deep-linking, facebook-share

I am working on an app in which I want to let the user share content on their facebook feed with app's link (just the way Soundcloud does it)

To achieve this, I have tried different things. I was able to share a simple picture and a link (separately) successfully, but when it came to sharing link of the app, I got stuck.

I have gone through most of the posts related to this. I have tried

[Facebook deep linking with iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684468/facebook-deep-linking-with-ios-app)

and

[How to implement iOS app link Facebook functionality in swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083226/how-to-implement-ios-app-link-facebook-functionality-in-swift-3)

but couldn't find anything appropriate. 
This doc:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios

could have been of help but it only shows how to handle incoming app links. My question is

**1. How do I share app link through my iOS App?**

Moreover it is mentioned:

> The link your app will receive will look like this:
>   `[url]?al_applink_data=JSON_ENCODED_DATA` 
>   Where url is the incoming URL
>   based on a custom scheme that you've defined for your app. You'll also
>   receive an al_applink_data query parameter with `JSON_ENCODED_DATA`
>   content that looks something like this:

```
 {
     "target_url": "https://www.example.com/abc.html",
     "extras": {
         "fb_app_id": [YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID],
         "fb_access_token": "[ACCESS_TOKEN']",
         "fb_expires_in": "3600"
     },
     "referer_app_link": {
         "url": "[FACEBOOK_APP_BACK_LINK]",
         "app_name": "Facebook"
     } }
```

> Where fb_access_token and fb_expires_in are only available if the
>   person has authenticated with Facebook in your app.

**2. How do I create the link?**

If this is the way to do it (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content and [Deep Linking Facebook iOS - App don't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083555/deep-linking-facebook-ios-app-dont-open))

> As an example, let's say you've got a page located at:
>
> http://example.com/applinks
>
> In that page you need to add some metadata to describe what app will
>   handle it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <!-- Other headers -->
</head>
<!-- Other HTML content -->
</html>
</head>
```

**3. Then where do I write this html?**

**4. From where do I get such `http://example.com/applinks` link?**

Right now I just have my app's custom schema which I have created in my `info.plist` file.

Comment: Answer to your question 3. can be found in what you quoted under 2.

Comment: 04FS? Where is the page in which i need to add meta data? 
I only have an iOS app.

Comment: The page you want to share, of course. App Links are a mechanism for you to have _your_ content open your app, if available.